# How to preserve the linebreaks in text when using cell content in an email?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I set up a worksheet with a button/macro that will produce an Outlook email template.

I am trying to lift the content for the email (which changes daily) from a specific cell to paste the email whilst retaining the spacing and line format that is in the Excel cell.

The code achieves this, except for when the email content is more than one line.

For example if I put the following in the target cell:

> Test
> Test
> Test

The email will show the content as:

> TestTestTest

```vb
Sub TestEmail()

Dim OApp As Object, OMail As Object, signature As String
Dim cFill As String
Dim cEmail As String
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim Content As String

Content = Worksheets("Misc").Range("K13").Value2
Content = Format(Content, "Fixed")

MyDate = Format(Date, "dd mmm yyyy")

''1

Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)
CurrentUser = Application.UserName

With OMail
    .Display
End With

signature = OMail.HTMLBody

With OMail
    myContent = "Good Morning," & _
      "<br>" & _
      "<br>" & _
      "Please see the attached." & _
      "<br>" & _
      "<br>" & _
      Content & _
      "<br>" & _
      "<br>" & _
      "Kind Regards," & "<br>" & "<br>" & CurrentUser

    .To = "test@test.com"
    .CC = "test@test.com"
    .Subject = "Test Email" & " " & MyDate
    .Attachments.Add pdfPath & LatestFile
    .HTMLBody = myContent & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & signature
    .Display
End With

End Sub
```

I tried various suggestions from other questions. Those tend to be Word->Word, Word->Outlook. I haven't found one that works for this specific issue.

The code has this line:

```
Content = Format(Content, "Fixed")
```

which appeared to work for a slightly different case than this.

I also tried:

```
Range("K13").Value
Range("K13").Text
```

As well as `XlPasteFormats` after copying, but this returned an error.

Comment: I think you the issue is that the linebreaks are written in anotherway and cant be pasted or something, i had a similar problem with the header and the linbreak is saved as the character chr(10) so i think an function which goes through the text line by line and adds the chr(10) would do it.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, I dont know how to implement that so I will wait and see what else is said.

Comment: The solution from @Raymond Wu is faster, did you  try it?

Answer (score 0):

For pasting the linebreaks you could use this function. It takes the Text, splits it at the linebreaks, then it loops through each line and adds an "
" to it.

```
Function linebreaker(Text as String)
textlines = Split(Text, Chr(10))
Text = ""
For Each Line In textlines
Text = Text & "<br>" & Line
Next
Debug.Print Text
linebreaker = Text
End Sub
```

Its only from my head so i didnt test it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after you get Value2 from the cell:

```
 Content = Replace(Content, vbLf, "<br>")
```

Basically it converts `vbLf` to HTML tag `<br>` which should be acceptable in the mail body.

Separately, you should declare all variables at all times, please insert `Option Explicit` at the top of your module to help you identify which variable are not declared.